# how to solve this error "specific cast is not availd "

Tags: c#

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    foreach (int i in list) {
        Process p =(Process) list[i];
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(p.process, p.arrival_time, p.burst_time);
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Process p = new Process();
    p.process =Int32.Parse( textBox1.Text);
    p.burst_time =Int32.Parse( textBox2.Text);
    p.arrival_time =Int32.Parse(textBox3.Text);
    list = new ArrayList();
    list.Add(p);
    textBox1.Clear();
    textBox2.Clear();
    textBox3.Clear();

}

public class Process {
    public int process;
    public int arrival_time;
    public int burst_time;
}
```

Comment: Which line gives you the error

Comment: What is the type of `list`? It seems odd that you would iterate over it as if it were a collection of `int` and then cast one of its elements to `Process`.

Comment: `foreach (int i in list) { Process p =(Process) list[i];`... I think you are mixing `for` loop and `foreach` loops..

Comment: I provided an answer. Could I help you? I would improve my post if it did not.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var obj in list)
{
    //list is ArrayList from what I saw
    Process p = (Process)obj;
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(p.process, p.arrival_time, p.burst_time);
}
```

I *suppose* list is `ArrayList` which contains `Process`,  because you are filling it in `button1_Click`, so you need to write it like this. Make a difference between `foreach` and `for` loop. Also use `List<Process>` in this case you don't need casting

Answer (score 0):

Use `TryParse` instead of `Parse`. Advantage: You don't get an exception if the parsing fails. You just check it with a boolean value:

```
bool Int32.TryParse(string s, out int result);
```

> Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the conversion succeeded.

**Example:**

```
int process = 0;

if (Int32.TryParse( textBox1.Text, out process)) {
    p.process = process;
} else {
    //do some other stuff
}
```

Furthermore the conversion of a list item to an `int` should not work, because your list has items of type `Process` (You do the conversion inside of the loop so I think that's the case). You also mixed a `foreach` with a `for` loop as @mybirthname already suggested. Use this instead:

```
var list = new List<Process>();

...

foreach (Process p in list) {
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(p.process, p.arrival_time, p.burst_time);
}
```